# Invalid parquet hive schema: repeated group array

Tags: hive, avro, parquet

Most datasets on our production Hadoop cluster currently are stored as AVRO + SNAPPY format. I heard lots of good things about Parquet, and want to give it a try.

I followed [this web page](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-convert-existing-data-into-parquet/), to change one of our ETL to generate Parquet files, instead of Avro, as the output of our reducer. I used the Parquet + Avro schema, to produce the final output data, plus snappy codec. Everything works fine. So the final output parquet files should have the same schema as our original Avro file.

Now, I try to create a Hive table for these Parquet files. Currently, IBM BigInsight 3.0, which we use, contains Hive 12 and Parquet 1.3.2.
Based on the our Avro schema file, I come out the following Hive DDL:

```
create table xxx {col1 bigint, col2 string,.................field1 array<struct<sub1:string, sub2:string, date_value:bigint>>,field2 array<struct<..............>>ROW FORMAT SERDE 'parquet.hive.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'parquet.hive.DeprecatedParquetOutputFormat' location 'xxxx'
```

The table created successfully in Hive 12, and I can "desc table" without any problem. But when I tried to query the table, like "select * from table limit 2", I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid parquet hive schema: repeated group array { required binary sub1 (UTF8); optional binary sub2 (UTF8); optional int64 date_value;} at parquet.hive.convert.ArrayWritableGroupConverter.<init>(ArrayWritableGroupConverter.java:56) at parquet.hive.convert.HiveGroupConverter.getConverterFromDescription(HiveGroupConverter.java:36) at parquet.hive.convert.DataWritableGroupConverter.<init>(DataWritableGroupConverter.java:61) at parquet.hive.convert.DataWritableGroupConverter.<init>(DataWritableGroupConverter.java:46) at parquet.hive.convert.HiveGroupConverter.getConverterFromDescription(HiveGroupConverter.java:38) at parquet.hive.convert.DataWritableGroupConverter.<init>(DataWritableGroupConverter.java:61) at parquet.hive.convert.DataWritableGroupConverter.<init>(DataWritableGroupConverter.java:40) at parquet.hive.convert.DataWritableRecordConverter.<init>(DataWritableRecordConverter.java:32) at parquet.hive.read.DataWritableReadSupport.prepareForRead(DataWritableReadSupport.java:109) at parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordReader.initialize(InternalParquetRecordReader.java:142) at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:118) at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:107) at parquet.hive.MapredParquetInputFormat$RecordReaderWrapper.<init>(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:230) at parquet.hive.MapredParquetInputFormat.getRecordReader(MapredParquetInputFormat.java:119) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getRecordReader(FetchOperator.java:439) at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:522) ... 14 more
```

I noticed that the error comes from the first nested array of struct columns. My question is following:

1. Does Parquet support the nested array of struct?
2. Is this only related to Parquet 1.3.2? Do I have any solution on Parquet 1.3.2?
3. If I have to use later version of Parquet to fix above problem, and if Parquet 1.3.2 available in runtime, will that cause any issue?
4. Can I use all kinds of Hive feature, like "explode" of nest structure, from the parquet data?

What we are looking for is to know if parquet can be used same way as we currently use AVRO, but gives us the columnar storage benefits which missing from AVRO.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Hive 12 cannot support the nest structure of parquet file, as shown in this Jira ticket.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8909